# Can anyone point me to CSLA app's running live on the Web?

Tags: csla

Can anyone point me to CSLA.Net app's running live on the Web?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.lhotka.net/Article.aspx?area=3&id=a26b2727-f99d-485b-aa3e-a5466e534a2b) if you are referring to CSLA.Net

Answer (score 1):

The forum software at http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/ was developed using CSLA.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hiringbox.com/ was developed with CSLA.Net 3.8